# Dynamically generate an image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a virtual gallery that dynamically generates an image (or set of images) based on what artwork is being shown and how large it is. I am having trouble keeping the image positions absolute when scaling the image size in my browser. That is, the images will scale unevenly when the browser display height changes. See the CodePen below for what I mean.

Does anyone have suggestions as to how to fix this? I noticed that Fine Art Multiple (click the link, then the View in Room button) seems to auto-generate their image using either a custom function or a 3rd party program. Does anyone know how I could viably do this, if what I want isn't possible in CSS?

Fine Art Multiple`s virtual gallery:
https://fineartmultiple.com/buy-art/alex-katz-reclining-figure/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FAM's example gallery works because it's not as responsive as yours. As you noted, it's a generated image that is positioned in the center.

Instead of using percentages I set some fixed widths for you and also moved the room image into a `background` property instead of having it as an additional `img` element.

I also made sure the person's silhouette disappears on small screens by shifting to the left and off-screen just like in the example.

Most of this positioning is reliant on a left `margin` combined with `transform`:

```
margin-left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,0);
```

This technique can be used to perfectly center and offset any element.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKpver?editors=0100

Comment: Thanks for your help! Would you mind relinking the codepen, I am having trouble opening it...

Comment: And do you have any recommendations for a 3rd party service (or method) that could allow me to dynamically create the image, like FAM?

Comment: I do not but I also don't think you have to. At least to my understanding the codepen I linked is pretty close.

Comment: Yeah your code pen is great! I was just more curious about how FAM is going about it. I found some javascript on their page that looks like does it, but it's way beyond me haha. Thanks again for all your help.